# Can't run powershell start-process with alternate credentials

Tags: scripting, powershell, credentials

tI am trying to run a powershell script from another powershell script using alternate credentials.

If I run:

```
$cred = get-credentials
$localArgs = "/c Powershell c:\myscript.ps1"

Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList $localArgs -Credential $cred -WindowStyle="Hidden"
```

the script errors with:

```
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

If I remove:

```
-Credential $cred
```

The script runs fine (but with the wrong credentials.)

Am I missing something in terms of how to use the -Credential agument?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the -Credential argument, you may need to also specify the -FilePath argument:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
start-process -FilePath C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe -Credential $cred
```